# How to make text and button fixed to background when using parallax effect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have my top section background fixed, and the section underneath scrolls on top of the background. The problem is, when I scroll, the text on the background on the top section scrolls, but I'd like it to be fixed to the background while still being bootstrap responsive. Here's my code:

```css
.topInfo {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)), url('/CMS_Static/Uploads/313864614C6F6F/exuma rocks 2.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.topInfoText {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 275px;
  font-size: 3.3em;
}

.bannerBtn {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<section class="topInfo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1 class="topInfoText text-center">Aerial Drone Services and Stock Footage</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <a class="btn bannerBtn btn-block" href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

add `position: fixed;` to the heading `topInfoText`  and `margin-top: 100vh` to button `bannerBtn` .

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.topInfo {
  background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), rgba(0, 0, 0, .25)), url('image here');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.topInfoText {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 275px;
  font-size: 3.3em;
  position: fixed; /* Change */
}

.bannerBtn {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  margin-top: 100vh; /* Change */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="topInfo">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h1 class="topInfoText text-center">Aerial Drone Services and Stock Footage</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <a class="btn bannerBtn btn-block" href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/dm6ubvc7/4/)